# Component clash with managed package - Invalid Dependency Bug

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

I have a managed package say Package A installed in the org with a namespace of "AnotherNamespace".

Package A has a component lets say "Main_Component" and "Component_B". It uses it as follows:

```
<aura:component description="Main_Component">
    <c:Component_B......./>
</aura:component>
```

I have another package lets say "Package B" with a namespace TheNamespace.

Package B has a component named "Wrapper_Component" and "Component_B". Wrapper Component uses it as follows:

```
<aura:component description="Wrapper_Component">
    <TheNamespace:Component_B....../>
</aura:component>
```

**Problem**

I tried to uninstall Package B but I get the error telling me that "Component_B" is in use by "Main_Component" which when drilled down shows it is in Package A not the package I am trying to uninstall.

Neither package has a dependency on the other.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this uninstalled short of creating a new Package A and changing all the `<c:.....>` namespaces to "AnotherNamespace"

**Update**

I modified the Package A to use its namespace instead of `c:` and upgraded the package. This did not solve the issue

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to Support?